# Regarding Bash/Shell script : How to (Add text) Instead of (deleting) all the text in the output file?

Tags: bash, sed

> output.txt (Original Before Script)
>   Apple mobile
>   Telephone
>
> `input.txt`
>
> ```
> Samsung Gallaxy
> Tablet
> Samsung S7 mobile
> Telephone
> Oneplus3 mobile
> Telephone
> ```

I use this command :
`sed -n -e '/mobile/,/Telephone/ p' input.txt > output.txt`

> output.txt
>
> ```
> Samsung S7 mobile
> Telephone
> Oneplus3 mobile
> Telephone
> Apple mobile
> Telephone
> ```

The result is almost perfect.. 
But i need the 4 lines at the end of the `output.txt`, without it deleting

```
> Apple mobile
> Telephone
```

please help :(

Comment: Do you mean to append? `>>` instead of `>`?

Answer (score 1):

`awk` would also achieve your goal,

```
$ awk '/Telephone|mobile/{print}' Input.txt >> Output.txt
$ cat Output.txt
Apple mobile
Telephone    
Samsung S7 mobile 
Telephone 
Oneplus3 mobile 
Telephone
```

Brief explanation,

- `/Telephone|mobile/`: search the lines contain `Telephone` or `mobile`, then print them.

Comment: It still replaces all the existing content from the output file :(

Comment: @ChristianJensen, can you show your expected output in the question?

Comment: @ChristianJensen, is this what you want? Append the searched result to output.txt

Comment: @ChristianJensen, If the answer helped you, please kindly check to accept my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use `grep`:

```
grep -E "(Telephone|mobile)" filename >>outputfilename
```